# LLM Chatbot on Streaming Real-time Data

Tags: postgresql, real-time, chatbot, large-language-model, llama

I'm trying to create an LLM chatbot for questioning and answering purpuse on Postgres data. I have some Postgre tables where data get inserted every n minutes. The user should be able to ask questions and chatbot must answer based on the newest inserted data. I'm not sure how to fetch the real-time data to the system.

Just to note, I need to use one of the local LLMs like Llamav2.

I need to build a "real-time" system that fundamentally revolves around processing streaming data—handling new information as it arrives and incrementally indexing it efficiently for LLMs.

To fetch the real-time data from Postgres to the pipeline, I could only find Pathway (https://pathway.com/developers/tutorials/connectors/database-connectors). As I'm new in this field, I was wondering if anyone has some experiences to share, thanks!

Comment: How about using a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: The tables are huge and a SELECT statement gets slow. Also, it exceeds the number of tokens.

Comment: No idea what a token is, but there is the option to add a `WHERE` clause to a `SELECT` statement to constrain the rows returned, for example to everything with a recent creation timestamp.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the reply but it's not what I'm looking for. A SELECT query is very slow in my case and doesn't work properly with Llama due to token limitations that I have.

Comment: That's a pity, because `SELECT` is really the only way to get data out of a database.